# How to paginate innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

First, my innerHTML looks like this:

```
function viewMusicFeed() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "getMusicFeed",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    success: function(obj) {
      getMusicFeed(obj);
    }
  });
}

function getMusicFeed(obj) {
  var userId = $("#userId").val();
  var list = '<section class="comment-list block">';
  $(obj).each(function(i, item) {
    if (item.musicfeedtitle == "Message") {
      list = list + '<article id="comment-id" class="comment-item">' + '<a class="pull-left thumb-sm avatar"><img src="resources/images/a9.png" alt="..."></a>' + '<span class="arrow left"></span>' + '<section class="comment-body panel panel-default">' + '<header class="panel-heading">';
      if (item.writerUser == userId) {
        list = list + 'My ' + item.musicfeedtitle + '' + '<span class="text-muted m-l-sm pull-right">' + '<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>' + item.writedate + '</span></header>' + '<div class="panel-body">' + '<div><pre>' + item.writemessage + '</pre></div>' + '<div class="comment-action m-t-sm">' + '<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" check="delete" data-index="' + item.musicfeedid + '">' + '<i class="fa fa-trash-o text-muted"></i> Remove</a></div></div></section></article>';
      } else {
        list = list + item.writerUser + '\'s ' + item.musicfeedtitle + '' + '<span class="text-muted m-l-sm pull-right">' + '<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>' + item.writedate + '</span></header>' + '<div class="panel-body">' + '<div><pre>' + item.writemessage + '</pre></div>' + '<div class="comment-action m-t-sm pull-right">' + '<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" check="report"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reportModal" data-index="' + item.musicfeedid + '">' + '<i class="icon-flag text-muted"></i> Report</a>' + '</div></div></section></article>';
      }
    } else {
      list = list + '<article id="comment-id" class="comment-item">' + '<a class="pull-left thumb-sm avatar"><img src="resources/images/a9.png" alt="..."></a>' + '<span class="arrow left"></span>' + '<section class="comment-body panel panel-default">' + '<header class="panel-heading">' + '<a href="searchAlbumSong?albumid=' + item.musicfeedtitle + '" class="hover">' + item.writemessage + '</a>' + '<span class="text-muted m-l-sm pull-right">' + '<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>' + item.writedate + '</span>' + '<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" data-index="' + item.musicfeedid + '">' + '<i class="fa fa-trash-o text-muted"></i></a></header></section></article>';
    }
  });
  list = list + '</section>';
  $("div.col-lg-12").html(list);
}
```

It's in innerHTML because I have another different set of this and those need to change at the click of a button. The outcome looks like that of Facebook. Since there will be a load of data, I need to paginate this. The problem is, all the paginate tutorial do not explain how paginate innerHTML. Is there a way to paginate innerHTML, or any other way to avoid innerHTML and start paginate from there?

- Here's the JSON data(I'm getting this from Spring MVC Controller):

  ```
  Array[11]
  0 : Object
    musicfeedid : "a120160427104913919"
    musicfeedtitle : "da15737e-3eb3-31e4-97f0-fe46299f75fb"
    reportmusicfeedSet :  null
    writedate : "2016-04-27 10:49:13"
    writemessage : "I liked New Generation"
    writerUser : "a1"
  __proto__ : Object
  1 : Object
  musicfeedid : "a220160425190136417"
  musicfeedtitle : "Message"
  reportmusicfeedSet : null
  writedate : "2016-04-25 19:01:36"
  writemessage :  "asdasdasdasdasdasdasdsd<div>report report report</div>"
  writerUser : "a2"
  __proto__ : Object
  2 : Object
  musicfeedid : "a120160424190033326"
  musicfeedtitle : "60bc9b01-196c-4849-bd6b-5894ed53521d"
  reportmusicfeedSet : null
  writedate : "2016-04-24 19:00:33"
  writemessage : "a2 liked Outsiders"
  writerUser : "a1"
  __proto__ : Object
          .
          .
          .
  ```

Comment: It seems it's better if we may have a look on how the JSON is being structured.

Comment: You need to paginate your JSON data on server side so your JS would receive paginated data. Then on your getMusicFeed function append the new data in your div instead of replacing the whole div by innerHtml.

Comment: So that common way to do pagination doesn't apply here? Is there any website or stackoverflow questions I should check?